# File information are not populating in stack trace when I am using the custom exception class in c#

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

I am throwing an exception from my code.  The issue is when I am throwing the generic exception class i can see the line numbers in stack trace. But as soon as I created my custom exception class the line numbers are coming as 0,0.

Following is the code snippet:

```
try{
  some code which can throw XYZException  
 }
 catch (XYZException e)
  {

    throw new MyCustomException("MyCustomMessage", e);
  }
```

following is the exception class which is utilizing stacktrace information to update exception message:

```
public class MyCustomException: Exception
{

    public MyCustomException()
    {
    }

    public MyCustomException(string message) : base( 
     GetExtraInfoFromStackTrace(message))
    {
    }

    public MyCustomException(string message, Exception innerException) : 
     base(GetExtraInfoFromStackTrace(message ), 
       innerException)
    {

    }

 static string GetExtraInfoFromStackTrace(String message)
    {
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(true);
       StackFrame[] frames= trace.GetFrames();
         message= GetExtraInfo(message,frames);
        return message;
    }


}
```

In stack trace info i am not getting any File information like line number and column number, but if i change the debug type to PDBOnly from portable type i can see the file info. 
Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong which is why the file information is not available in stack trace.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No-one is likely to be able to help you without seeing some relevant code etc.

Comment: Thanks ADyson , I have updated the question with code example.

Comment: override `ToString()` on your custom exception? It's not clear what's happening in your code or what do you expect to see vs what do you actually see

Comment: I want to show the information of main files with line and column number for user interest from where exception information traverse. For example:I want the message to be update with. The exception occur in following lines and column of following files: file(line, column) .   But line and column are always coming as zero.

Comment: Looks like new StackTrace(true) is never showing frame information with line number and column number with portable pdb.

Comment: Sten Petrov do u need extra info for my issue. Can you please help or guide me in some direction to resolve this issue.